# Where should questions about deployment, versioning and rollout be asked?

Tags: discussion, support

There are lots of questions that come up when thinking about getting software productive.

Like how to do versioning of the software, how to deploy it on client side and generally how to roll software out.

Having done this multiple times in different ways, there are still lots of open questions.

If I ask them on stackoverflow, they will get closed with very high probability.
They are not to programming related, I cannot provide code, they seem to be 
ideally suited for "off topic".

So: Where can I ask those questions?

**-edit-**

To have more concrete example of the questions that I would like to ask:

- What to consider before rolling software out?
- How to version a bunch of assemblies without having to edit lots of config files?
- How to keep software on client side up to date?
- ...

I would really appreciate to ask those questions myself, if there is a place for it somewhere. SO seems to be no match.

Comment: It's the "how to" part of your suggested topics that makes me hesitate to answer it. Would you happen to have an example of something you'd like to ask?

Comment: @Bart Please have a look at my updated question

Answer (score 3):

Such questions *might* be on-topic for [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). From their [topics help page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who
>   are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about
>   software development. If you have a question about...
>
> *[...]*
>
> - software engineering
>
> *[...]*

I'd say that rolling out software is a software engineering problem. There certainly is a [`deployment` tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) on the site already.

Just be careful about avoiding your question being a request for resources (blogs, books, etc.), share your research so far, and keep things constructive.

Comment: I really don't see that as in the *actual* scope of the site. Whilst their FAQ states it *might* be on-topic, I don't think I've ever seen a question about that sort of thing on programmers.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Software deployment is something many software engineers are concerned with. Strategies to implement proper deployments are within the realm of Programmers, in my opinion.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: just because you haven't seen any questions on that topic yourself doesn't mean that the topic is therefor off-limits.

Comment: Well, it's something software developers and coders are concerned with too, so maybe it should go on SO.

Comment: SO is very strict on what is on topic and what is not. I do not think that my questions would be open there for more than a couple of minutes.

Comment: @djechlin: rule of thumb: at the keyboard coding and run into an error? Post on SO. At the whiteboard, planning stuff? Post on Programmers.

Comment: I'm starting a test-baloon on programmers then ;)

Comment: That actually sounds like a really good rule of thumb. That should be blatant in both FAQs.